# CASE WHEN for XMLATTRIBUTES (SQL oracle)

Tags: sql, xml, oracle, oracle11g

I can't apply `CASE WHEN THEN`, when creating XML.
maybe I should use `IF ELSE`, but I'm creating a regular query.
I should have a condition:

```
CASE WHEN 1+2=true
 THEN attribute "A"
 ELSE attribute "B"
END
```

Example:

```sql
SELECT XMLROOT(               
               XMLELEMENT("attrib",                          
                          CASE
                            WHEN (1 + 2) = 3 THEN
                             (XMLATTRIBUTES('a' as "A"))
                            ELSE
                             (XMLATTRIBUTES('b' as "B"))                          
                          END))
  FROM dual
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Because

- The `CASE..WHEN` expression is stated at the wrong location
- `XMLROOT` function has missing arguments
- The single quotes should wrap the identifiers(**a**,**A**,**b**,**B**) rather than
  double quotes
  The `EVALNAME` keywords preceding **'A'** and **'B'** are missing

you can rearrange the existing statement as below considering those facts;

```sql
SELECT XMLROOT(CASE
                 WHEN 1 + 2 = 3 THEN
                  XMLELEMENT("attrib", XMLATTRIBUTES('a' AS EVALNAME 'A'))
                 ELSE
                  XMLELEMENT("attrib", XMLATTRIBUTES('b' AS EVALNAME 'B'))
               END,
               VERSION '1.0',
               STANDALONE YES)
  FROM dual;
```

**But** `XMLROOT` is *deprecated*, and [`XMLSERIALIZE`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/database/oracle/oracle-database/19/adxdb/generation-of-XML-data-from-relational-data.html#GUID-55FE9CED-5B25-4DA2-9F9E-921DF8276EB8) function is recommended by Oracle rather than that. So, use the following as alternative to your case

```sql
SELECT XMLType(CASE
                 WHEN 1 + 2 = 3 THEN
                   XMLSERIALIZE(
                       CONTENT XMLELEMENT("attrib", XMLATTRIBUTES('a' AS EVALNAME 'A'))
                    VERSION '1.0'
                   )
                ELSE
                   XMLSERIALIZE(
                       CONTENT XMLELEMENT("attrib", XMLATTRIBUTES('b' AS EVALNAME 'B'))
                    VERSION '1.0'
                   )                  
                 END).getStringVal()            
  FROM dual;
```

Answer (score 0):

From the [`XMLELEMENT` documentation](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/server.102/b14200/functions220.htm):

> The objects that make up the element content follow the `XMLATTRIBUTES` keyword. In the `XML_attributes_clause`, if the `value_expr` is null, then no attribute is created for that value expression.

You want to put the `CASE` expression inside `XMLATTRIBUTES` and have one for each attribute:

```sql
select XMLROOT(
         XMLELEMENT("attrib",
           XMLATTRIBUTES(
             CASE WHEN 1 + 2 =  3 THEN 'a' END AS "A",
             CASE WHEN 1 + 2 <> 3 THEN 'b' END AS "B"
           )
         ),
         VERSION '1.0'
       ) AS xml
FROM   DUAL;
```

*Note: You also need the `VERSION` argument for `XMLROOT`.*

Which outputs:

> | XML |
> | --- |
> | <?xml version="1.0"?> <attrib A="a"/> |

*db<>fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_11.2&fiddle=185cfeebc89ee7f3696e859da8a145c3)*